# "error: expected expression" when using extra parentheses

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors, parentheses

I just stumbled across a compiler error that I was not expecting:

```cpp
std::cout << sizeof(int)   << std::endl;  // ---> this is valid (obviously)
std::cout << sizeof((int)) << std::endl;  // ---> this leads to
                                          // "error: expected expression"
```

Similarly, we have:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T value;
};
Foo<int>   f1;  // ---> this is valid (obviously)
Foo<(int)> f2;  // ---> this leads to "error: expected expression"
```

Apparently, the compiler interprets `(T)` as an explicit conversion and stops there. I understand the error, I understand what the compiler is expecting, what I do not get is why `(T)` cannot be treated as `T` if it is not in the context of `(T)(exp)`. I thought that the compiler would be able to see through that (and probably return a warning), so I suppose this means that there are ambiguous cases where allowing those extra parentheses would lead to errors.

My questions are: when would that be dangerous? Is that in the C++ standard?

This was tested with clang 3.3. and g++ 4.7.2.

Comment: Well its looking for some value to convert and when there isn't one it complains. Why is this surprising?

Comment: @legion: The problem is not the error in itself, but what lead to this situation. With C++11 and things like `auto` or `decltype`, I sometime forget that this kind of situation can arise. There may be ways for the compiler to see that `(T)(exp)` is different than `(T)` and treat things differently, which is not the case. That's what I would like to understand better.

Comment: @BenC Would you also expect to be able to declare `(int) i = 0;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` expects either a **value** (an expression) or a type. `(int)` is neither one of them - you can't treat types as values and expect them to act correctly in cases where you would expect values to do so, because they are not (first-class) values. Therefore, you can't just parenthesize a type and have the same type come out.

Comment: Indeed, this `sizeof` is actually how I stumbled across that (mis-parenthesizing while refactoring some code), which is why I decided to test with a different example. The compiler can do amazing things (e.g. the latest C++11 features), but it still fails here. I understand what's happening here (this is also in my question), I just don't understand what leads to that (`(T)` can never be anything but a type casting in this case). Also, I did not downvote.

Comment: @BenC It can be only a typecasting because that's the only context in which the syntax `(T)` makes sense. As I mentioned, a type in itself is not an expression. Hence you can't expect that `T` be the same as `(T)`.